# Getting a 401 OPTIONS for a fetch GET call with headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

Ive been struggling with connecting to an API since almost a day now, and I tried many different things but none of them have worked yet.. The app works fine with a fake server, but it trips when Im using the actual API using their VPN. Is the way Im sending the headers wrong? I thought it might be CORS, but sending a Postman to the same gives the right response as expected. Any tips please ?

```
await fetch(       
http://url/restservices/cricket/v1/das/SubscriptionServices/Event?func=getEventIdBySubscriptionId&subscription_id=[ID]&event_start=2018-07-12T17:40:49&event_end=2018-07-27T20:40:49`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: new Headers({
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            Authorization:
              "Basic [TOKEN]",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          })
        }
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Just checking, but are you putting an actual auth token in the `"Basic [TOKEN]"` string?

Comment: You token is not correct or it's expired

Comment: Nope, had to hide it for security purposes.. My bad. the token goes like "Basic Ajdnsdfjn..."

Comment: Try adding `mode: 'no-cors'` to your headers object

Comment: None of this works.. I also tried sending 'mode' but still no luck..